# Getting "Not a recognized flag:" on AIX for simply using "ls" and "rm" w/o flags

Tags: aix

I started getting  "Not a recognized flag:" error for simply running "ls" command without any flags, In AIX. Same problem is with "rm" command.

The strange thing is that it used to work before.

I saw several questions about getting this error when using commands with flags that are not supported by AIX. But here, I am running without any flags.

Here is an example print that I get:

```
ls
ls: Not a recognized flag: -
ls: Not a recognized flag: =
ls: Not a recognized flag: y
Usage: ls [-1ACFHLNRSabcdefgiklmnopqrstuxEUX] [File...]
```

Thank you!

Comment: turn on shell debug/trace in your terminal session with `set -vx`. You  should see what is really being executed when you type `ls`. It is likely you have typo in your `$HOME/.profile` and you are either creating an `ls` alias or function OR that ls is "interacting" with an existing alias or function. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

What shellter said (in essence):  You can do

```
type ls
```

and it should say:

```
ls is a tracked alias for /usr/bin/ls
```

My guess is you have a file named ls that is an executable in your current directory.  Or, you could have an alias or function within the shell.

You can also give a full path to avoid the issue:

```
/usr/bin/ls
```

and that should avoid aliases, functions, and rogue executables named ls.

Comment: Shellter, pedz - thank you guys!
It was indeed an alias `ls="ls --color=tty"` that was "hidden" in one of the scripts that I run. I guess that these flags are indeed not supported in AIX.
The problem was resolved after I did `unalias ls`